# error when connecting flutter app with flutter_bluetooth_serial

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, flutter-dependencies, bluetooth-socket

I'm getting this error when trying to connect with a divice;

```
Connecting to 00:A5:54:BB:95:3F (id: 1)
I/BluetoothAdapter(20241): cancelDiscovery
I/BluetoothAdapter(20241): cancelDiscovery = false
D/BluetoothUtils(20241): isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null
I/BluetoothSocket(20241): connect() for device 00A554 called by pid: 20241
W/BluetoothAdapter(20241): getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
E/flutter (20241): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(connect_error, read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1, java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
```

this is the code snippet of the function:

```
void connectToDevice(String address) {
  BluetoothConnection.toAddress(address).then((connection) {
    BluetoothConnection bluetoothConnection;
    bluetoothConnection = connection;

    // ...

    bluetoothConnection.input?.listen((List<int> data) {
      // Use a logging framework instead of print
      // Example: logger.info('Received data from the device');
      print('Received data from the device');
    }).onDone(() {
      // Use a logging framework instead of print
      // Example: logger.info('Disconnected by remote request');
      print('Disconnected by remote request');
    });
  });
}
```

these are the code snippets of the function to enable bluetooth and show paired devices the below ones workes but not the code for connecting

```
void enableBluetooth() {
  FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance
      .requestEnable(); // Request Bluetooth to be turned on
}

void getPairedDevices(BuildContext context) {
  FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance
      .getBondedDevices() // Get list of paired devices
      .then((List<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Paired Devices'),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: pairedDevices.map((device) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  child: Text(device.name ?? ''),
                  onTap: () {
                    connectToDevice(device.address);
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  });
}
```

Please help me to solve this.

I tried to add permissions:

```
void main() {
  requestPermissions(); // Call requestPermissions function
  runApp(MyApp());
}

void requestPermissions() async {
  Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
    Permission.location,
    Permission.storage,
  ].request();
  print(statuses[Permission.location]);
  print(statuses[Permission.storage]);
}
```

it didn't show any progress,
tried to recall the function continuously till it is connected still didnt work.